# GPS coordinates to OLEX

Tags: gps, convert, format

My goal is to convert gps coordinates to the format which the OLEX plotter has, so I can import them as marks.

So I created a point at `64 10.239N` and `51 41.523W`
I exported the point, and the file says `3850.2395026` `-3101.5235411` `1495562630`
The last one seems to be the time, and is not important to me at this point.

So my question is: what format does the OLEX plotter have?
And possibly how to calculate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this is simple.
The decimal degrees just needed to be multiplied by 60.
In other words: The values in the file are minutes.

```
64.1707 × 60 = 3850.24
-51.692  × 60 = -3101.52
```